# Why model = newModel does not work but model.title = newModel.title works?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to edit my record in database. I don't think that I'm doing it good enough. I've tried make code shorter by `dev = newDev;` but it is not saving it then.

Code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(Dev newDev)
{
    try
    {
        if (TryUpdateModel(newDev) == true)
        {
            var dev = _db.Devs.Where(x => x.ID == newDev.ID).Single();
            dev.Title = newDev.Title;
            dev.Body = newDev.Body;
            dev.Tags = newDev.Tags;
            dev.Image1 = newDev.Image1;
            dev.Image2 = newDev.Image2;
            dev.Image3 = newDev.Image3;
            dev.Image4 = newDev.Image4;
            _db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Fail.");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Can you help me optimize my code here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please provide more details, and give us a fully working code sample including saving to your context.  Where does `newModel` come from, for example?  Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: model = newModel surely works. But maybe you are executing this in a method and expect that change to be present also in method that called the one that made the change? In that case it won't work. If you want to be able to do this you have to pass variable by reference ( void methodName(ref Model model) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework (it looks like it?) then you can't update entities this way.

The Entity Framework uses change tracking to understand what changes have happened to an entity.  To do this, it keeps a list of the specific instances that are loaded from that context, and what their initial state was, so it can detect what changes have been made to those instances before you call `SaveChanges` on the context.

When you assign directly to a reference type, you're just reseating the reference.  You aren't changing the initial object instance.  Existing references to that instance (like the one the Entity Framework keeps internally to keep track of changes) don't change, and you will end up pointing at different object instances.

So, just use your code the way you have it now.  This is the only way to blindly update every field.  If nothing was updated, the Entity Framework's change tracking should cause `SaveChanges` to do nothing.  If something was updated, it will perform the corresponding SQL to persist the changes to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to read up on the memory model used by .NET. Setting `dev = newDev` is going to change the value of the `dev` *variable*, but variables have a local scope. It won't change the value of other variables that were referencing the same object.

In this case, the context that you pulled `dev` from is probably keeping track of the `dev` that it pulled out and gave to you, so if you change its properties and call *SaveChanges* then it will know which values to change.

If you're just trying to copy all the values from one object to another without having to manually write a line of code for each property, you should be able to [use a tool like AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to automatically map all the similarly-named properties from one object to another.

Comment: +1 for the automapper suggestion.  That will let you reduce the amount of code you have to write to copy all the fields over to the DB-tracked object instance.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work, then:
1. dev is a reference type
2. A reference of dev is being changed to point to another object (newDev)

Which means, that you're already working with an object out of context. And to be able to update that object, you first ned to somehow attach that object to the context and make the context be aware of that its the updated object of some existing entity there.

Hope this will help.